# FAIL - Application at context path /camunda could not be started

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I have to setup the Camunda standalone web application on Apache Tomcat by dropping it in the webapps directory.

I am getting an error while starting the application.

> FAIL - Application at context path /camunda could not be started
>
> FAIL - Application at context path /engine-rest could not be started

**Server Information**

> Tomcat Version : Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
>
> JVM Version : 1.7.0_111-b01
>
> JVM Vendor : Oracle Corporation
>
> OS Name : Linux
>
> OS Version : 3.19.0-25-generic
>
> OS Architecture : amd64
>
> Hostname : MyHost
>
> IP Address : 127.0.1.1

**Java**

> java version "1.8.0_101"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
>
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1072      manual mode

**Javac**

> javac 1.8.0_101
>
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac          1072      manual mode

**Catalina.log**

Oct 07, 2016 10:14:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart

Oct 07, 2016 10:14:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/camunda] startup failed due to previous errors

Oct 07, 2016 10:21:05 AM org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment 
INFO: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.impl.application.DefaultApplication
Oct 07, 2016 10:21:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart

Oct 07, 2016 10:21:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/engine-rest] startup failed due to previous errors

**localhost_access.log**

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:09:01:37 +0530] "GET /engine-rest/engine HTTP/1.1" 404 1005

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:32 +0530] "POST /openam/service/ServerEditSecurity HTTP/1.1" 200 307

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:33 +0530] "GET /openam/UI/Login?service=adminconsoleservice&goto=http://localhost:8080/openam/base/AMAdminFrame HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:33 +0530] "GET /openam/XUI/ HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:36 +0530] "GET /openam/json/serverinfo/* HTTP/1.1" 304 -

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:36 +0530] "POST /openam/json/users?_action=idFromSession HTTP/1.1" 401 73

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:36 +0530] "GET /openam/XUI/locales/en-US/translation.json?v=13.0.0 HTTP/1.1" 404 1051

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:37 +0530] "POST /openam/json/authenticate?service=adminconsoleservice&goto=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fopenam%2Fbase%2FAMAdminFrame&authIndexType=service&authIndexValue=adminconsoleservice HTTP/1.1" 200 771

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:40 +0530] "POST /openam/json/authenticate HTTP/1.1" 200 151

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:41 +0530] "POST /openam/json/users?_action=idFromSession HTTP/1.1" 200 322

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:41 +0530] "GET /openam/json/users/amadmin HTTP/1.1" 304 -

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:41 +0530] "POST /openam/json/users?_action=validateGoto HTTP/1.1" 200 74

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:42 +0530] "GET /openam/base/AMAdminFrame HTTP/1.1" 200 143

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:42 +0530] "GET /openam/json/global-config/realms?_queryFilter=true HTTP/1.1" 200 226

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:43 +0530] "GET /openam/realm/RMRealm HTTP/1.1" 302 -

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:45 +0530] "GET /openam/json/serverinfo/* HTTP/1.1" 304 -

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:45 +0530] "POST /openam/json/users?_action=idFromSession HTTP/1.1" 200 322

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:46 +0530] "GET /openam/json/users/amadmin HTTP/1.1" 304 -

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:46 +0530] "GET /openam/XUI/locales/en-US/translation.json?v=13.0.0 HTTP/1.1" 404 1051

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:46 +0530] "GET /openam/json/serverinfo/version HTTP/1.1" 304 -

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:46 +0530] "GET /openam/json/serverinfo/version HTTP/1.1" 200 86

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:47 +0530] "GET /openam/json/global-config/realms?_queryFilter=true HTTP/1.1" 200 226

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:47 +0530] "GET /openam/json/global-config/realms?_queryFilter=true HTTP/1.1" 200 226

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:47 +0530] "GET /openam/json/serverinfo/version HTTP/1.1" 304 -

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:51 +0530] "GET /openam/realm/RMRealm?RMRealm.tblDataActionHref=/&requester=XUI HTTP/1.1" 200 21194

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:52 +0530] "GET /openam/task/Home?Home.tabCommon.TabHref=4&jato.pageSession=AKztAAVzcgARamF2YS51dGlsLkhhc2hNYXAFB9rBwxZg0QMAAkYACmxvYWRGYWN0b3JJAAl0aHJlc2hvbGR4cD9AAAAAAAAMdwgAAAAQAAAABHQAFENDVGFicy5TZWxlY3RlZFRhYklkdAABMXQAEkN1cnJlbnRQcm9maWxlVmlld3QAAS90AAxjdXJyZW50UmVhbG10AAEvdAAiY29tLWlwbGFuZXQtYW0tY29uc29sZS1sb2NhdGlvbi1kbnEAfgAHeA$$&requester=XUI HTTP/1.1" 200 37666

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:52 +0530] "GET /openam/com_sun_web_ui/images/tabs/level2_background.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 654

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:52 +0530] "GET /openam/com_sun_web_ui/images/tabs/level3_selected.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 338

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:52 +0530] "GET /openam/com_sun_web_ui/images/tabs/level1_selected.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 336

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:52 +0530] "GET /openam/com_sun_web_ui/images/tabs/level2_deselect.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 644

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:52 +0530] "GET /openam/com_sun_web_ui/images/table/gradtblttl.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 646

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:11:52 +0530] "GET /openam/com_sun_web_ui/images/table/gradtblhdr.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 843

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:12:01 +0530] "GET /openam/service/SCConfigAuth?SCConfigAuth.tabCommon.TabHref=442&jato.pageSession=AKztAAVzcgARamF2YS51dGlsLkhhc2hNYXAFB9rBwxZg0QMAAkYACmxvYWRGYWN0b3JJAAl0aHJlc2hvbGR4cD9AAAAAAAAMdwgAAAAQAAAABHQAFENDVGFicy5TZWxlY3RlZFRhYklkdAABNHQAEkN1cnJlbnRQcm9maWxlVmlld3QAAS90AAxjdXJyZW50UmVhbG10AAEvdAAVb3BlbnNzby5TZWxlY3RlZFRhYklkdAABNHg$ HTTP/1.1" 200 22675

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:12:01 +0530] "GET /openam/com_sun_web_ui/images/table/check_all.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 348

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:12:01 +0530] "GET /openam/com_sun_web_ui/images/table/uncheck_all.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 240

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:12:01 +0530] "GET /openam/com_sun_web_ui/images/table/sort_up_sel.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 88

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:12:01 +0530] "GET /openam/com_sun_web_ui/images/table/sort_up_nonsel.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 169

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:12:01 +0530] "GET /openam/com_sun_web_ui/images/table/gradtblhdrsrt.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 837

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:12:05 +0530] "GET /openam/service/ServerSite?ServerSite.tblDataServerActionHref=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fopenam&jato.pageSession=AKztAAVzcgARamF2YS51dGlsLkhhc2hNYXAFB9rBwxZg0QMAAkYACmxvYWRGYWN0b3JJAAl0aHJlc2hvbGR4cD9AAAAAAAAMdwgAAAAQAAAABXQAFENDVGFicy5TZWxlY3RlZFRhYklkdAADNDQydAASQ3VycmVudFByb2ZpbGVWaWV3dAABL3QADGN1cnJlbnRSZWFsbXQAAS90ABVvcGVuc3NvLlNlbGVjdGVkVGFiSWR0AAM0NDJ0AB5TZXJ2ZXJTaXRlLnRibFNlcnZlci5zdGF0ZURhdGFzcQB-AAA_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 HTTP/1.1" 200 27102

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:12:07 +0530] "GET /openam/service/ServerEditGeneral?ServerEditGeneral.tabCommon.TabHref=422&jato.pageSession=AKztAAVzcgARamF2YS51dGlsLkhhc2hNYXAFB9rBwxZg0QMAAkYACmxvYWRGYWN0b3JJAAl0aHJlc2hvbGR4cD9AAAAAAAAMdwgAAAAQAAAABnQAFENDVGFicy5TZWxlY3RlZFRhYklkdAABMXQAEkN1cnJlbnRQcm9maWxlVmlld3QAAS90AAxjdXJyZW50UmVhbG10AAEvdAAVb3BlbnNzby5TZWxlY3RlZFRhYklkdAADNDQydAAQcGdBdHRyU2VydmVyTmFtZXQAHGh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODA4MC9vcGVuYW10AB5TZXJ2ZXJTaXRlLnRibFNlcnZlci5zdGF0ZURhdGFzcQB-AAA_QAAAAAAADHcIAAAAEAAAAAt0ABZzaG93UGFnaW5hdGlvbkNvbnRyb2xzc3IAEWphdmEubGFuZy5Cb29sZWFuzSBygNWc-u4CAAFaAAV2YWx1ZXhwAXQAEnNlY29uZGFyeVNvcnRPcmRlcnB0ABBhZHZhbmNlZFNvcnROYW1lcHQAEWFkdmFuY2VkU29ydE9yZGVycHQABHBhZ2VzcgARamF2YS5sYW5nLkludGVnZXIS4qCk94GHOAIAAUkABXZhbHVleHIAEGphdmEubGFuZy5OdW1iZXKGrJUdC5TgiwIAAHhwAAAAAXQAEXNlY29uZGFyeVNvcnROYW1lcHQADXNlbGVjdGlvblR5cGV0AAhtdWx0aXBsZXQACG1heFBhZ2Vzc3EAfgAVAAAAAXQAF2FkdmFuY2VkRmlsdGVyQXZhaWxhYmxlc3EAfgAPAHQAD3ByaW1hcnlTb3J0TmFtZXQAEXRibERhdGFTZXJ2ZXJOYW1ldAAQcHJpbWFyeVNvcnRPcmRlcnQACWFzY2VuZGluZ3h4 HTTP/1.1" 200 38677

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:12:09 +0530] "POST /openam/service/ServerEditSecurity HTTP/1.1" 200 28080

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:12:16 +0530] "POST /openam/service/ServerConfigInherit HTTP/1.1" 200 28593

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:12:19 +0530] "POST /openam/service/ServerConfigInherit HTTP/1.1" 200 36636

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:12:44 +0530] "GET /openam/service/ServerEditSecurity?ServerEditSecurity.tabCommon.TabHref=423&jato.pageSession=AnjajZM9bxNBEIbHDhYxCcJOwDSA-AXnKEphpYFgZOGCEGGLgorx3cRetN49dsdfDYIGClroKCgo8ycQNQUFDRWihxaJijmfDRc5CTnpTnezc-_MvM_uwQ8oeAflxzjEYMBKB3fQ9-5iXDj79cPHyqPPS5BvwDltMWpgyNY1ocg9R75ndTSOb9yE5FodLcuzJHeR4bwyivewS22HSjPkNhku1utt7PigRZpCpkg-mhHD0tamLK7VB86R4T1n95WmB4pG8leVYTVMF-4T6n4aumRjMt7bRaUtUZKoG5KrW7Ovuk3TI6c44I4W5ZgcT3axTz7wjEy3kdE_gacACzOsSEueQmsidJOWdXzPReRihopMPZLJlEFW1kgZdlb7v_5pNN3glrWa0Hy67p59efv7Zx5yD6EwRD2gcQwMJYyGaEKKEuGkH9EtZ2PzYuVDLcwyz8Ti6-F6TcPUJbf2_d37X89f1qRec17PQelf3u6g3yH34uDN1ZXX317lAaQdgJzw8lMrZaD2JCaG5f5As4q1vF6eN9YQkOR2hgIUO5qmxpUgycVxgtpPI5VUsBQ71c9ax1BEH5KJlOkyXMgsJ2MxrAuihEcW0zjR6e4wu5RpmnmlxxxvV6vahqh71vN2baO2UU02BcoOuZbmthRTgj39Og3v48hO58wdtx9OzTLFlrHoSLgngDjS5__SWXS6PHM66-mJuATD-uzs-szZSo_u-A9JOWks HTTP/1.1" 200 25351

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:12:49 +0530] "GET /openam/service/ServerEditSession?ServerEditSession.tabCommon.TabHref=427&jato.pageSession=AnjalZM9bxNBEIbHDhYxSRQ7IaEBxC84RyGFlQaCkYULQoQjCirGd5PzovXusTv-ahA0UNBCR0FBmT-BqCkoaKgQPbRIVMz5bOIoJsBJd7qdnZ3Z9312D79BwTsoP8QeBl1WOriFvn0bk8LZz-_erz_4OAf5OpzTFqM6hmxdA4rcduTbVkeD5Np1SJ_F_rx8S_IWGZaUUbyHMe07VJoht8lwvlbbx5YPmqQpZIpk0IgY5rY2rzKs1LrOkeE9Zw-UpnuK-rKqwrAYZhN3CXUnC63ZhIz39mSlLWkjUdcjV7PmQMUN0yanOOCWlsoJOR7uYod84BmZbiKjfwSPAU5oWGBYF3190aAMsrJGCrKz2v92SqOJgxvWakLz4Yp78un1z-95yN2HQg91lwYJiCxPoTURumHTOr7jInIJQwmjHpqQojSY7kdi5enYJPFMIhYeb9gwTDG5la9v3v54-rwqDRuThg5KR3m73U6L3LPDV5cWXn55kQeQ_QDkpNGxLY27L_mRlSJzf5gQw3ynq1klevSLg5SkHzm1lhW5MNltXeiS2-kJZWxpGuUsi_DlxKnOVA-GVWGQGj7NQayYyhupZiiiD8lEysSDdD7eYXYZ02zJxTZzsl2paBuiblvP29WN6kYlPRQoJ-RylttUTCn2bPQvvGez-tMpGAnN_QfLmb5ngKeMPQXEXz2fSepUg2dxKo85HVkuGFbHd9dP3a3s6g5-AVJkaSg$ HTTP/1.1" 200 30441

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:13:08 +0530] "GET /openam/service/ServerEditAdvanced?ServerEditAdvanced.tabCommon.TabHref=425&jato.pageSession=AnjajZM9bxNBEIbHCRYxCcJOwDSA-AXnKIoUKw0EIwsXhAhbFFSM7yZ3i9a7y-74q0HQQEELHQUFZf4EoqagoKFC9NAiUbHns-EiJyEn3el2dnY-3mfn4AcUnYXKYxxg0Gchgzvokrtoime_fvhYffR5ERaacE5qjJoYsrYtKHFiySVaRiNz4yakz8pwyX_L_i0xnBdK8B7G1LEoJENhg-Fio9HBrgvaJClkivyiFTEsbm5sMaw2-taS4j2r94WkB4KG_lSNYSXMNu4Tyl5muqQNKef0fKRNn8Zb7YBsQ6t9EbdUQlZwwF3pIxuyPN7FHrnAMTLdRkb3BJ4CzPWw7EtyFGoVoR23teV7NiJrGKq-66HvTChkoZVPw1ZL91c_iSoObmktCdWn6_bZl7e_fy5A4SEUByj7NDLAUMZogCqkKA2c1uPjVvK2WbLKoRKmnmeM1_VwvpZiismufn_3_tfzl3WfrzXLZ6H8z2-33-uSfXHw5ury62-vFgB8OQAFz8tNpPQNdcaGGJZ6fcnCSP97eVZY04MkuzPwQLEraSJcGVJfHKWo3cRSzQKWjRW9vHQMJXQhqUiomOFCbjtti2HNI0p55DGN0jjxDrPNmGaeVxJms12rSR2iTLTj7fp6fb2WXgr0N-Ra5tsWTCn2bHUa3seRnfRZOO4-nJplhi0n0ZFwTwBxpM7_pTOvdGWqdF7TE3F5DGvT2XW52cpGd_QHW_RpNg$$ HTTP/1.1" 200 23886

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:13:23 +0530] "GET /openam/service/ServerConfigXML?ServerConfigXML.tabCommon.TabHref=421&jato.pageSession=AnjalZM9bxNBEIbHCRYxSRQ7IaEBxC-woyhIVhoIRhYuCBG2KKgY303Oi9a7x-74q0HQQEELHQUFZf4EoqagoKFC9NAiUTHns8lFMQFOutPt7OzMvu-ze_gN8t5B6SH2sdxjpcu30HduY5w_-_nd-40HH-dhrg7ntMWwjgFb14ACdxz5jtXhML52HZJnabAg36K8BYZlZRTvY0Qth0oz5LYYztdqLWz7cpM0BUyhDBohw_z21lWG1VrPOTK87-yB0nRP0UBWVRiWgnTiLqHupqF1G5Px3p6stC1tJOr65GrWHKioYTrkFJe5raVyTI5He9glX_aMTDeR0T-CxwAnNCwybIi-gWhQBllZIwXZWe1_O6XRROUb1mpC8-GKe_Lp9c_vc5C7D_k-6h4NYxBZngJrQnSjpnV8x4XkYoYihn00AYVJMNmPxErZ2DTxTCwWHm_YMEwRudWvb97-ePq8Kg0b04YOikd5e71um9yzw1eXFl9-eTEHIPsByEmjY1uadF_2YytFZmsUE8NCt6dZxXr8i8OEpB87tZ4WuTDdbV3oktvtC2VsaxrnrIjwldipbqYHw5owSAzPchArMnlj1QwF9AGZUJlomMxHu8wuZZouudhhjncqFW0D1B3reae6Wd2sJIcC5YRcTnObiinBno7-hfdsVn86BWOhuf9gOdP3FHDG2FNA_NXzmaRONXgWp9KE05HlgmFtcnd95m6lV3f4C1niaSw$ HTTP/1.1" 200 25823

127.0.0.1 - deepak [07/Oct/2016:10:13:40 +0530] "POST /manager/html/start?path=/camunda&org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=B613298E09C607A7D7E380C36E24B6F8 HTTP/1.1" 403 3208

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:13:43 +0530] "GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -

127.0.0.1 - deepak [07/Oct/2016:10:13:43 +0530] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 25102

127.0.0.1 - deepak [07/Oct/2016:10:13:47 +0530] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 25102

127.0.0.1 - deepak [07/Oct/2016:10:13:47 +0530] "GET /manager/images/asf-logo.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -

127.0.0.1 - deepak [07/Oct/2016:10:13:47 +0530] "GET /manager/images/tomcat.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -

127.0.0.1 - deepak [07/Oct/2016:10:14:01 +0530] "POST /manager/html/start?path=/camunda&org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=0F6DC3E667E1DD965D2F150ACC6B8478 HTTP/1.1" 200 25165

127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2016:10:18:44 +0530] "GET /camunda/ HTTP/1.1" 404 985

127.0.0.1 - deepak [07/Oct/2016:10:20:45 +0530] "GET /manager/html/list?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=76C9F9D032B38FAE6CD427838304329E HTTP/1.1" 200 25102

127.0.0.1 - deepak [07/Oct/2016:10:21:06 +0530] "POST /manager/html/start?path=/engine%2Drest&org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=6379A010902601AC524B664E2070F872 HTTP/1.1" 200 25169

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the required camunda+3rd party libs to the "lib/" dir in tomcat as well?

Comment: I have added libraries as .jar files to the location /var/lib/tomcat7/lib.

Comment: Applications were running at /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps

Comment: When I restarted tomcat, Its failed to start after stopping the server. Removed the lib directory (contains jar files) from /var/lib/tomcat and now, I was able to start Tomcat again.

Comment: Maybe its a good idea to download the working camunda-tomcat bundle and get to know the stack a bit before trying something custom? It really should work, but from your trace and description, I doubt anyone will be able to support.

Comment: I have updated the entire camunda bundle in the application, and I felt I am closer. I am getting [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999732/no-process-engine-found-camunda-webapp-cannot-work-without-a-process-engine) error now.