# No process engine found. camunda Webapp cannot work without a process engine

Tags: bpmn, camunda

When I set up a camunda BPMN platform, I got the following error

> HTTP Status 500 -
>   org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.IllegalWebAppConfigurationException: No
>   process engine found. camunda Webapp cannot work without a process
>   engine

Confirming that the both the '/camunda' and '/engine-rest' is deployed and running in Tomcat.

But /engine-rest returns 404 with following error.

> description : The requested resource is not available.

Please help!.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the shared process engine for your server as described in https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/installation/full/tomcat/manual/#add-bpm-platform-xml

Comment: Have checked http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/engine to get the list of all engines of the platform. But it returns NULL ('[ ]')

Answer (score -1):

Have added bpm-platform.xml to '/conf'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpm-platform xmlns="http://www.camunda.org/schema/1.0/BpmPlatform"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.camunda.org/schema/1.0/BpmPlatform http://www.camunda.org/schema/1.0/BpmPlatform ">

  <job-executor>
    <job-acquisition name="default" />
  </job-executor>

  <process-engine name="default">
    <job-acquisition>default</job-acquisition>
    <configuration>org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration</configuration>
    <datasource>java:jdbc/ProcessEngine</datasource>

    <properties>
      <property name="history">full</property>
      <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate">true</property>
      <property name="authorizationEnabled">true</property>
      <property name="jobExecutorDeploymentAware">true</property>
    </properties>

  </process-engine>

</bpm-platform>
```

Comment: And this fixed your problem? How is this different from my proposed solution below?

Comment: No, it doesn't fixed the problem. No changes!

Comment: Then why do you add this as an answer? If you want to comment or discus, using comments is the better choice ... I will flag this one.